# How to use index with the itertools function in Python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, lambda, python-itertools

I have a list which contains multimple lists inside it and it looks like this:

```
import itertools

stand_city = 11
stand_liverpool = 6.5

premier_league = [
             ['A1','Manchester City', '10,1', 'Aguero'],
             ['A2','Manchester City', '11,2', 'Mahrez'],
             ['A3','Manchester City', '13,5', 'Sterling'],
             ['B1','Liverpool', '4,5', 'Mane'],
             ['B2','Liverpool', '5,6', 'Salah'],
             ['B3','Liverpool', '7,2', 'Jota']]
```

Now for every list I want to get the last value before it exceeds either `stand_city` or `stand_liverpool`. Depending on `index[1]` in the lists. If its `Manchester City` I need it to use `stand_city`, if `Liverpool` I want it to use `stand_liverpool`. I want those values to be stored in a new list.

**This is my code:**

```
new_list  = []
for key,sublists in itertools.groupby(premier_league,lambda y:y[0]):
    club = (list(sublists)[0][1])
    if club == 'Manchester City':
        v=[] 
        for v in itertools.takewhile(lambda x:float(x[-2].replace(",","."))<stand_city ,sublists):
            pass
        if v: 
            x = v[-1]
            new_list.append(x)
    elif club == 'Liverpool':
        v=[] 
        for v in itertools.takewhile(lambda x:float(x[-2].replace(",","."))<stand_liverpool ,sublists):
            pass
        if v: 
            x = v[-2]
            new_list.append(x)
            
print(new_list)
```

**This is my output:**

```
[]
```

**This is my desired output:**

```
10,1
5,6
```

Comment: Why do you use `y[0]` in `itertools.groupby(premier_league,lambda y:y[0])` and not `y[1]` (the club name)?

Comment: Why is `4,5` included in the desired output? It is not the last value before the value for Liverpool exceeds 6.5

Comment: mkrieger1 True, thats a mistake. I edited my desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some small modifications to your code to get the result you want.

```
stand_city = 11
stand_liverpool = 6.5

premier_league = [
             ['A1','Manchester City', '10,1', 'Aguero'],
             ['A2','Manchester City', '11,2', 'Mahrez'],
             ['A3','Manchester City', '13,5', 'Sterling'],
             ['B1','Liverpool', '4,5', 'Mane'],
             ['B2','Liverpool', '5,6', 'Salah'],
             ['B3','Liverpool', '7,2', 'Jota']]

res = []
for g, value in groupby(premier_league, key = lambda x:x[1]): # group by according to index 1
    less_than = [] # temporary list to hold all values less than your threshold for a particular group
    for i in value: # iterate thorugh the values in each group
        float_i = float(i[2].replace(',', '.')) # convert index 2 to float
        to_compare = stand_city if g == 'Manchester City' else stand_liverpool
        if float_i < to_compare: # compare `float_i` with either `stand_city` or `stand_liverpool` based on group
            less_than.append(i[2]) # add all values that meet the condition to a temp list
    res.extend(less_than[-1:]) # take only the last element from the list for each group, `[-1:]` is done to prevent cases where `less_than` is an empty list
print(res) # ['10,1', '5,6']
```

Or in a shorter way

```
from itertools import groupby
res = []
for g, value in groupby(premier_league, key = lambda x:x[1]):
    last = [x[2] for x in value if float(x[2].replace(',', '.')) <= (stand_city if g == 'Manchester City' else stand_liverpool)][-1:]
    res.extend(last)

print(res) # ['10,1', '5,6']
```

Fixed OP's code to work

```
import itertools

new_list  = []
for key,sublists in itertools.groupby(premier_league,lambda y:y[1]):
    if key == 'Manchester City':
        v=[] 
        for v in itertools.takewhile(lambda x:float(x[-2].replace(",","."))<stand_city ,sublists):
            pass
        if v: 
            x = v[-2]
            new_list.append(x)
    elif key == 'Liverpool':
        v=[] 
        for v in itertools.takewhile(lambda x:float(x[-2].replace(",","."))<stand_liverpool ,sublists):
            pass
        if v: 
            x = v[-2]
            new_list.append(x)
            
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did? It looks good and much shorter.

Comment: let me break it out

Comment: @TangerCity would that do?

Comment: Oke thank you I will check it out. Well the next question is why did my code not work and what would I need to solve my code?

Comment: your group by index was wrong as mentioned by @mkrieger1

Comment: Do you know how a generator works? TL;DR when you do `club = (list(sublists)[0][1])` you are consuming the generator and the for loops have nothing to iterate over

Comment: So what do I need to change in that line to make it work?

Comment: check my answer now, I have fixed the code

Comment: Your great men! Thx